# Reactjs - Imitate Excell cells range copy feature

Tags: c#, reactjs, csv, copy, clipboard

I need the help from you all for table copy feature on a Reactjs web app.

There have a C# software in which if I copy Excel cells range and paste there to software, it will show the cells with exact text and style

On our web app, we have a table and a button COPY. Requirement is: after click copy => paste to the C# software, it will behave exactly the same to the case copying from excel

The C# software is a 3rd party tool, and all I know about its implementation for "pasting" feature is: it recognizes excell range by checking csv format from clipboard data

```
`if(Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue)`
```

What I have tried in webapp is:
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-galois-tgcg6t?file=/src/App.js

1. User copy Excel range => paste to the input box => web handle paste event by read all clipboard data => I dont see data of csv format there. I only see text/plain, text/html and image/png
2. User Click Imitate Copy button => pushing all data (read in #1) to clipboard => user paste to a dummy C# software => the `If` statement of C# return false

My questions are:

- Is that actually csv not supported in browser clipboard (which explain why when paste excel to web, i dont see clipboard csv data)
- if it's supported, anyone can please point me out how to put csv to clipboard

Thanks in advance!